# Python 2.7.6 error when building from source: gcc.orig: directory": No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, rhel

I've been provisioned a very bare-bones RHEL 4.4 at work; e.g., it didn't have java or gcc installed.

I have followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4) to install python 2.7.6 on another VM (RHEM 4.6) successfully. However on this new vm, I cannot `make` without getting this error:

```
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE \
          -DSVNVERSION="\"`LC_ALL=C echo Unversioned directory`\"" \
          -DHGVERSION="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
          -DHGTAG="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
          -DHGBRANCH="\"`LC_ALL=C `\"" \
          -o Modules/getbuildinfo.o ./Modules/getbuildinfo.c
gcc.orig: directory": No such file or directory
<command-line>: warning: missing terminating " character
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c: In function â_Py_svnversionâ:
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c:63: error: missing terminating " character
./Modules/getbuildinfo.c:63: error: expected expression before â;â token
make: *** [Modules/getbuildinfo.o] Error 1
```

I tried what was suggested in this unrelated [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue6094) report:

```
SVNVERSION="Unversioned directory"
./configure
make
```

but received the same error.

I saw this question on super user, which suggests to check the output of the `svnversion` command in the `Modules` directory, but I don't have `svn` or `svnversion` on this machine. It also suggests to edit the function `_PY_svnversion` in `Modules/getbuildinfo.c`, which I did but received the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Ok I found the answer in my case:

issue `configure` which will create a new `Makefile`
edit the `Makefile` with vi.

search for SVNVERSION and set it to

```
SVNVERSION=    ""
```

[image]

`make` will then work.

Comment: I had the same issue with 2.7.13 and this fixed it.

Comment: @Doug I don't see what the person has in his screenshot in my configure file, and I'm on 2.7.8. What did you change exactly? What was the SVNVERSION set to previously?

Comment: SVNVERSION was set to something (I don't recall what) that caused the error. Setting it to blank (I believe) turns off SVN support, which is something I didn't need, and fixed the issue. Hope that helps...I don't recall more details.